# assign foreach to variable using php

Tags: php, foreach

I have this code

```
foreach ($codes as $code => $total)  {
    printf("%s <font color='blue'><b>Total clicks = %d<br></b></font>", $code, $total); 
}
```

Which gives me the output

```
01 output 1 Total clicks = 1
02 output 2 Total clicks = 1
03 output 3 Total clicks = 1
03 output 4 Total clicks = 1
03 output 5 Total clicks = 1
```

etc

How can I assign the output to a variable to use in a mailout i.e.

```
$message5 = each line of output
```

so that my mail out shows the same ouput

```
01 output 1 Total clicks = 1
02 output 2 Total clicks = 1
03 output 3 Total clicks = 1
03 output 4 Total clicks = 1
03 output 5 Total clicks = 1
```

a member suggested using sprintf so I tried this

```
foreach ($codes as $code => $total)  {
    printf("%s <font color='blue'><b>Total clicks = %d<br></b></font>", $code, $total); 
    $message5 = sprintf("%s <font color='blue'><b>Total clicks = %d<br></b></font>", $code, $total); 
}
```

But it only gives me the last line of output
user3783243 suggests that

```
$message5 =  overwrites on every iteration
```

How can I stop the overwrite?

Please note this issue has now been resolved

Comment: sprintf only gives me the last line of output

Comment: Use `$message5 .= sprintf(...`

Comment: `$message5 = ` overwrites on every iteration

Comment: yes how to stop the overwriting?

Comment: What was already sent `.=` assigns to existing variable.

Comment: Commenters, please vote to close duplicates instead of commenting solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try with this

```
    $message = '';
            
    foreach ($codes as $code => $total)  {
        $message .= sprintf("%s <font color='blue'><b>Total clicks = %d<br></b></font><br>", $code, $total); 
    }

    echo $message;
```

Comment: works in the echo on screen but does not give the output in the mailout

Comment: what is the mailout? how are you trying to use it? assign each line to a dynamic variable? or the full data in a single variable?

Comment: what is the mailout? maybe is better to describe the whole scenario you have in mind - WDYT?

Comment: trying to use $message5 to assign each line of output in the email, so I have $message = $message1. " ".$message2. " ". $message3. " ". $message5, my email line is  mail($emailaddress[$z], $emailsubject, $message, $headers);

Comment: @mark.four It should work. Are you sure you changed `=` to `.=`?

Comment: Barmar yes the problem appears to be in my mail line,  mail($emailaddress[$z], $emailsubject, $message, $headers); when I add the $message5 array it does not mail out, do I need to change the mail out line to accept an array?

Comment: [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)

Answer (score 0):

As I adhere from the comments and the questions you want to concatenate each message separately

```
$final_message = []; 
foreach ($codes as $code => $total)  {
    printf("%s <font color='blue'><b>Total clicks = %d<br></b></font>", $code, $total); 
   // message5 or 4 it doesn't matter it will get each message on each iterate
    $message5 = sprintf("%s <font color='blue'><b>Total clicks = %d<br></b></font>", $code, $total); 
    $final_message[] = $message5;
}
var_dump($final_message); // $final_message[0], $final_message[1] etc..
```

Comment: Mostafa Ezzat, thanks, works on the screen, but Still only gives the last line on the mail line,  mail($emailaddress[$z], $emailsubject, $message, $headers);

Comment: try 
`$final_message = imploade("", $final_message);
mail($emailaddress[$z], $emailsubject, $final_message , $headers);`

Comment: [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)

Answer (score 0):

If I assume your `$codes` variable matches below data, then it would work without any issue... if still doesn't work please show us whole code to check...

```
$codes = array(
    '01 output 1' => 1,
    '02 output 2' => 1,
    '03 output 3' => 1,
    '03 output 4' => 1,
    '03 output 5' => 1,
);

$message5 = '';

foreach ( $codes as $code => $total )
{
    $message5 .= sprintf( "%s <font color='blue'><b>Total clicks = %d<br></b></font>", $code, $total ); 
}

mail( $emailaddress[$z], $emailsubject, $message5, $headers );
```

Comment: [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)